# Problem with %lld on Windows

Tags: c, windows

Why does this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%lld\n", 4294967296LL);
}
```

emit this for Windows:

```
0
```

but this for Linux:

```
4294967296
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because Visual Studio C++ 2003 and earlier do not support %lld. But this code will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%I64d\n", 4294967296LL);
}
```

[Size and Distance Specification (Visual Studio C++ 2003)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6(VS.71).aspx)

[Size and Distance Specification (Visual Studio C++ 2005)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: It's nice to know that 2005 started supporting %lld.