# Why is the use of cin, cout or %I64d preferred over %lld specifier in C++?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, iostream, format-specifiers, long-long

Why do many of the online judges advise *"do not use the `%lld` specifier to read or write 64-bit integers in С++"*?

Is it preferred to use the `cin`, `cout` streams or the `%I64d` specifier?

Comment: Because you can't be sure `long long` is 64 bit long, for example?

Comment: Because using `printf` is not type safe. If user passes some other type then it gives you Undefined behavior. While with `cout` the compiler appropriately chooses an valid overload version depending on the type or it returns an error, there is no Undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlokSave but why %I64d has been preferred over %lld ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664015/problem-with-lld-on-windows

Comment: The first comment under the Q answers that for you.My comment answers the second Q. To be more specific on the first comment. `%l64d` is the format specification which tells the compiler that the number passed as argument will be `64` bit long. But it is not necessary that the type `long long` used to store these numbers are actually `64` bit on every environment. Any mis-match in format specification and actual data being passed to `printf` technically gives you an Undefined behavior. So this type unsafe behavior might bite you badly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the answer is related to `%lld` means `long long decimal`, which isn't guaranteed to be 64-bit. It could be, for example 128 bit on some systems. (Although if the variable is `long long` rather than, say, `uint64_t`, then I expect `%lld` is the right thing to use - or it would go wrong the other way around)

Unfortunately, the design of `printf` and `scanf` and their siblings is such that the compiler implementation and the format must match.

Obviously, `cout` and `cin` are safe in the sense that the compiler will chose the right output and input translation in itself.

It may also have something to do with what compiler(s) the "online judges" use - I think Microsoft compilers at some point supported 64-bit integers, but not `long long`, and thus didn't have `%lld`, but did have `%l64d`.

Comment: I came across this link http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/417# which says:                                                                      If you submit under "GNU C++" or "GNU C" option, use this:
   printf("%I64d\n",n);
but NOT this:
   printf("%lld\n",n);

If you submit under "MS C++" option, both variants should work.

Comment: I suspect that's because GNU C is actually using an older MS VC runtime library (since glibc isn't readily available for Windows).

Answer (score 5):

The `<<` and `>>` operators on `cin` and `cout` have versions for every integer and floating-point type. If you use `cin` and `cout`, you just do `cin >> integer_variable` or `cout << integer_variable` and you're done, `cin` and `cout` will figure out what to do.

If you use some sort of `printf()`, then you must be very careful in what you pass to it. If you pass to it an `int`, you must also pass its type specifier `"%d"`, for `unsigned int` it's `"%u"`, for `long` it's `"%ld"`, for `unsigned long long` it's `"%llu"`, for `size_t` it's `"%zu"` and so on. If you pass a type specifier that doesn't match the type of your integer, you'll invoke *undefined behavior*. As a result, your program may print wrong numbers or corrupt itself or hang or crash or misbehave in some other mysterious way.

Now, the C++11 language standard (and C99) has at least one integer type that's 64-bit or longer, `long long` (and its unsigned counterpart, `unsigned long long`). If you use it, you must be aware that it can be longer than 64 bits. If your compiler provides another type, `__int64` or `int64_t` (plus the unsigned version of the same), that's exactly 64-bit, you shouldn't mix and match their type specifiers as it's often mistakenly done. You should still use `"%lld"` and `"%llu"` for `long long` and `unsigned long long` and whatever's appropriate for `__int64` (perhaps, `"%I64d"`) and for `int64_t` (`PRId64` macro).

Basically, you should either avoid using `printf()-like` functions or be very careful with them.

Answer (score -1):

`Ans to 1:` Because in their background they use compiler. `GNU` supports `%l64d`, and `MS` supports `%lld` and `%l64d`.

`Ans to 2:` Yes, it is preferred to use the `cin`, `cout`. Because internally they take decision by their own.